# Please make question merge notice a little bit clearer

Tags: feature-request, merged-questions

The text on the merge reason of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186657/146015) is almost gobbledy-gook if you just read it left to right - I had to go back and read it again to grok what it was saying.

**Suggestion:** can we add single or double quotes around the target question's title, or maybe italicise the title?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I prefer italics on the possibility the question title *contains* quotes. In that case, we would have to replace the question's title's quotes with single quotes to follow what we're taught in Engrish claz, but that would put yet *another* task on the developers, **sorry**: "all powerful overlords".

<sub>And we don't want that</sub>

Comment: Good point @Cole, I prefer italics myself. The way it is presently I thought I was reading one of those generated review queue audits where the system drops random text or phrases into an otherwise okay question.